# array declaration in c++ without specifying the size

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

in c# I can do this:

```
private double[,] elevations;
```

How to do the same in c++ without specifying the size or elements of array on this line?

Comment: For dynamically sized arrays, use `std::vector`

Comment: @onsmith no you can't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **cannot** do that for arrays in C++.
But, if you want dynamic size, go for [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

And from your question, I see that you are interested in a 2D array. Hence, use a nested `std::vector`, like this:

```
vector< vector< double > > elevations;
```

Comment: A vector of `vector<double>`s.

Comment: @DonLarynx Exactly. :)